# Bash multiple and or logic operation

Tags: bash, boolean-logic

Trying to basically do something equivalent to 
`(a && b) || (c && d)` in bash.

Currently I have this, but it's not working, and it's just the result of me playing around with syntax..

```
if [[ -f $TRASH/.$arg && -f $arg ]  || [ -d $TRASH/.$arg && -d $arg ]]
```

Originally I was just checking if two files exist, but I need to expand to see if the files OR directories exist.

Comment: `[[ "$a" == "1" && "$b" == "1" ]] || [[ "$c" == "1" && "$d" == "1" ]]  && echo okay`

Comment: Thanks for that lol, I feel bad asking such a simple question on here but I was having trouble finding an answer to it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Note: you might want to use `[[ -e $TRASH/.$arg && -e $arg ]]` in case one's a file and one's a directory, or one's a symlink, or...

Comment: You can also just drop the "inner" `] .. [`, since `&&` and `||` have the expected precedence inside `[[ ... ]]`

Answer (score 0):

bc is an arbitrary-precision math and logic calculator.  For cygwin bash, bc must be explicitly installed.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$1
b=$2
c=$3
d=$4
echo $a $b $c $d

res=$(bc <<< "($a && $b) || ($c && $d)")
echo $res
```